# ActionScript 3.0 for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, actionscript

I'm currently developing an application in ActionScript 3.0, and GVim isn't really working well with it. Are there are any plugins for Eclipse that allow ActionScript functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Adobe Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder-family.html) is built on Eclipse.

Or, you can install the [Flex SDK plugin](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html) for Eclipse.

Comment: So, what's the URL to load the addon when importing the Flex SDK Plugin?

Comment: There's no download site via Eclipse Software Updates / Marketplace.  Adobe offered [3.0.2 Eclipse Plugin](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=flex_eclipse) directly from their site; other SDK can be downloaded and configured.  Adobe Flash Builder is phenomenal as Eclipse comes prepackaged; however, is only available as a commercial product.

Comment: So is it free? I'm an existing customer, I bought Adobe CS6 recently

Comment: Flash Builder is part of Adobe CS6 Master Collection.  Adobe Flash Builder is a commercial app; whereas, the Flex SDK plugin is free.  What version of CS6 do you have?

Comment: I have Design and Web Premium. Do you think it will have it? I'm also very familiar with Flex and use MXMLC all the time.

Answer (score 1):

At this time (2015) there are no usable free Eclipse plugins for AS3 development as far as I know. Adobe's Eclipse plugin is dead, FDT free version is all but worthless and as3ide isn't working with the current Eclipse.

But there is [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/), it isn't based on Eclipse but is quite usable as an AS3 IDE. It is completely free and open source.